# MySQL daily data starting from specific time

Tags: mysql, date, time

How to get daily sum of counter readings from 8am to 8am of next day?

```
create table Tbl (counterID int, `timestamp` datetime, `counter` int);
insert into Tbl values
(1, '2017-09-18 07:07:03', 22);
insert into Tbl values
        (1, '2017-09-18 08:08:03',     25);
insert into Tbl values
        (1, '2017-09-18 19:08:33',     30);
insert into Tbl values
        (1, '2017-09-19 10:14:54',      8);
insert into Tbl values
        (1, '2017-09-19 10:15:24',     13);
insert into Tbl values
        (1, '2017-10-20 04:21:08',      5);
insert into Tbl values
        (1, '2017-10-23 14:21:38',     24);
insert into Tbl values
        (1, '2017-10-23 14:22:08',     72);
insert into Tbl values
        (1, '2017-10-23 14:22:38',     86);
insert into Tbl values
        (1, '2017-10-24 03:23:09',    100);
insert into Tbl values
        (1, '2017-10-24 04:23:38',    120);
insert into Tbl values
        (1, '2017-10-24 04:24:08',    125);
insert into Tbl values
        (1, '2017-10-25 14:56:52',      2);
insert into Tbl values
        (1, '2017-10-25 14:57:22',      8);
insert into Tbl values
        (1, '2017-10-25 16:39:22',     21);
insert into Tbl values
        (1, '2017-10-25 16:41:52',     22);
insert into Tbl values
        (1, '2017-10-25 16:42:22',     23);
insert into Tbl values
        (1, '2017-10-25 17:18:13',     26);
insert into Tbl values
        (1, '2017-10-25 17:21:15',     17);
insert into Tbl values
        (1, '2017-10-25 17:21:46',     19);
insert into Tbl values
        (1, '2017-10-25 17:22:46',     41);
insert into Tbl values
        (1, '2017-10-26 08:41:58',      2);
insert into Tbl values
        (1, '2017-10-26 14:02:28',      5);
insert into Tbl values
        (1, '2017-10-30 13:39:20',      1);
insert into Tbl values
        (1, '2017-10-30 13:40:19',      4);
```

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the Solution for your query, check out:

```
select counterid,date(ts2) ts,sum(counter) counter_sum
from (select counterid,counter,convert_tz(ts,'+08:00','+00:00') ts2
        from tx3) s
group by counterid,date(ts2);
```

Output

```
+-----------+------------+-------------+
| counterid | ts         | counter_sum |
+-----------+------------+-------------+
|         1 | 2017-09-17 |          22 |
|         1 | 2017-09-18 |          55 |
|         1 | 2017-09-19 |          21 |
|         1 | 2017-10-19 |           5 |
|         1 | 2017-10-23 |         527 |
|         1 | 2017-10-25 |         179 |
|         1 | 2017-10-26 |           7 |
|         1 | 2017-10-30 |           5 |
+-----------+------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Couldn't get this line: "from tx3) s"

Comment: Table 'tx3' doesn't exist

Comment: use your table "Tb1" instead of tx3

Comment: Keeps saying "Unknown column 'ts' in 'field list'" pointing to convert_tz(ts,'+08:00','+00:00'). Looks like internal conflict? Whereas this part works without error: "select counterid,counter,convert_tz(timestamp,'+08:00','+00:00') ts2 from Tbl"

Comment: Use your column name timestamp instead of ts

Comment: Ok, working version is "select counterid,date(ts2) ts,sum(counter) counter_sum from (select counterid,counter,convert_tz(timestamp,'+08:00','+00:00') ts2 from Tbl) s
group by counterid,date(ts2);"

Comment: Both your solution and Michal solution producing the same result but yours is shorter, although required some workaround, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
select counterid, start, end, sum(counter) from (
    select counterid,
           case when cast(timestamp as time) < '08:00:00' then date_add(cast(`timestamp` as date), interval -1 day)
                else cast(`timestamp` as date) end `start`,
           case when cast(timestamp as time) < '08:00:00' then cast(`timestamp` as date)
                else date_add(cast(`timestamp` as date), interval 1 day) end `end`,
           counter
    from tbl
) `a` group by counterid, start, end
```

Comment: Works about well! I don't know why I get doubled counter sums. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: @Taha Please accept the answer and optionally upvote :)